# passing value to function php

Tags: php, function

```
function foo($bar) {
    $qux = strpos('abcdef', $bar);
    if ($qux) {
        $qux += 1;
    } else {
        $qux = -1;
    }
    return $qux;
}
$x = foo('abc');
$y = foo('def');
```

I have the function above and I am confused as to how to answer the question below. I know that the function will accept a parameter then use it to check if it exists in a string then put that value to a variable since in PHP true or false is 1 or 0 or is incremented or decremented depending if the string is found.
Now I am confused on how to answer the below questions.

I just want to know how to answer the questions below. 
Example `$x is 1, $y is 4`

```
$x = foo('abc');
$y = foo('def');
```

Since `'abc'` is found it is true value of `$qux` is `1 plus 1 equals 2 then the function returns 2 $x will be 2`.

Then how to answer `$x is 1, $y is 4`?

What are $x and $y?

1. $x is 1, $y is 4
2. $x is -1, $y is 4
3. $x is -1, $y is 5
4. $x is 2, $y is 5

Comment: Open please `strpos` manual and see a red block with `==` and `===` explanation.

Comment: And I don't understand what is the exact question. What are these variants for?

Comment: @u_mulder Ive read it. In the condition it did not compare. My question is how to answer `$x is 1, $y is 4` I am really confused.

Comment: `strpos()` count from 0 not 1

Comment: `if ($qux !== false)`

Comment: @u_mulder the question `What are $x and $y?` which is confusing for me. I dont know how to answer it what is why I asked here. I know how the function works but I dont know how to answer the question

Comment: What does it mean - what are x and y? X is a result of a function call. Y is too.

Comment: Well, right now the anwser is : `$x is -1, $y is 4` if you just copy/paste your code and echo $x and $y

Comment: yes that is  what I can see from the function it. The value of x or y is the result of `foo('abc')` which could be 2 when true or -1 when false because true is 1 when increment becomes 2 or false 0 decrement becomes 0

Comment: `strpos` is `0` and `3`.   `0` is false-ish and `3` is true-ish. The rest you can figure out yourself.

Comment: @Adder that cleared alot for me I can work that out Thank you can you provide that as answer and link as well to that docs? I dont know that one

Comment: You have to ask a very specific question in such way that it would help the fellow developer community. You shouldn't ask questions which involve discussions like these. Also, try reading the documentation of functions used with the proper investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `$x = foo('abc');` => call foo() and that function returns a result.

On `foo()`:

```
$qux = strpos('abcdef', $bar); // strpos() search for `abc` & will found it and results 0 because strpos() index start from 0.

if ($qux) {
$qux += 1; // here $qux = 0 + 1, which is 1
} else {
$qux = -1;
}
return $qux; // 1 returned to called function ie, $x.
```

And so $x is 1 & similarly $y comes as 4

Syntax of `strpos()`

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

The `strpos()` function finds the position of the first occurrence of a string inside another string.

**Note**: The `strpos()` function is case-sensitive.

**Note**: This function is binary-safe.

**Parameters**

**Haystack** 
    The string to search in.

**Needle** 
    If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.

**Offset** 
    If specified, search will start this number of characters counted from the beginning of the string. If the offset is negative, the search will start this number of characters counted from the end of the string.

And the main point to note is(and probably put you in trouble):

***strpos() counts position from 0 not 1***

Comment: This answer provided all the necessary explanation for me to understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is -1 and 4.

The reason is, `abc` is at position 0, or 0 is considered to be `false` if you check it as a boolean, hense

`if ($qux) with $qux =0` will give `$qux = -1`.

For `def, $qux = 3. $qux > 0` so $qux is true so `$qux +=1` so `$qux =4`

Answer (score 1):

For the two cases, strpos is 0 and 3. 0 is false-ish and 3 is true-ish. So `$x = 0-1 = -1` and `$y = 3+1 = 4`.